# Simple voxel-block melee removing script

Tags: c#, voxels, raycasting, unity

I'm trying to create a voxel based game, now I want my character to remove blocks with a melee weapon, but I'm not sure which way to go.

I mean is it the only way to get the Block with a raycast? I don't really want a rigibody weapon and the blocks with a trigger btw. . So if the raycast is the solution, how is it done? I don't get my code running, I just want to shoot a ray for a short distance in the facing direction, or better in the mousedirection. I've found a lot of code to do that but none is working for me :( here is my code so far.

```
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        var v3 = Input.mousePosition;
        v3.z = 16.0f;
        v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (v3);

        Vector3 worldMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (v3);

        var direction = worldMousePosition - transform.position;
        direction.Normalize ();

        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, direction, out hit, 100)) {
            print ("There is something in front of the object!");
        }

    }
```

So my world looks like follows: I got a 3d Sidescrolling game, so the character is moving on x and y axis, the z axis of the world is on -16 btw. thats because i change the z value of the raycast. It doesnt work with 16 nor -16. I think this direction part is not fine, because the values are kinda odd.

Comment: ah sorry forgot about that, this script is on the player and the code is from the update method :)

Comment: Also, where exactly does your code fail? Does Physics.Raycast fail or does it maybe already fail at Input.GetButtonDown? Does the Update method get executed at all? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No no errors, I just don't get a hit with my raycast and i don't know why, I feel like the direction calculation is kinda wrong

Comment: Are you aware that you are running your mouse position through `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` *twice*?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the main problem, now im "shooting" in the wrong direction, but I think I can solve that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your mouse coordinates through `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` twice.

```
    var v3 = Input.mousePosition;
    v3.z = 16.0f;
    v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (v3);
    Vector3 worldMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (v3);
```

Deleting the 3rd line will help.

When you also have the problem that you are shooting in the opposite direction, it will help to replace:

```
var direction = worldMousePosition - transform.position;
```

with

```
var direction = transform.position - worldMousePosition;
```